# find elements of an array between linspace values

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a sorted array A ranging continuously between 0 and 1 and an array B=linspace(0,1,21).

I want to find the elements of A that lays between the successive intervals defined by B. For example:

```
A= [ 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.006];
B= [0 0.05 0.1 ....1];
```

I would like to find

```
C = [1 2 3; 4];
```

because the first three elements of A are between 0 and 0.005 and the fourth is between 0.005 and 1.

I cannot figure out the way to do it without a for loop. Does anyone have some alternative?

Comment: I think you mean `B=linspace(0,1,21)` ? And also you all your numbers should have one decimal place fewer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C = [1 2 3; 4];` is not a valid MATLAB structure. You could have `C = {1 2 3; 4};` but I would suggest maybe rather `C = [1,1,1,2]` where the numbers in `C` represent the position in `B` of the largest element that is smaller than the corresponding element of `A`.

```
A= [ 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06];
B= linspace(0,1,21);
```

Then

```
C = max(cumsum(bsxfun(@gt,A,B')))
```

We use `bsxfun` to compare which elements of `B` the elements of `A` are larger than:

```
bsxfun(@gt, A, B')

ans = 
    1   1   1   1
    0   0   0   1
    0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0
    ...
```

Now we just have to find the last row that a `1` is in for each column. There are many ways to do this, I used `max` and `cumsum`:

```
cumsum(bsxfun(@gt, A, B'))

ans = 
    1   1   1   1
    1   1   1   2
    1   1   1   2
    1   1   1   2
    1   1   1   2
    ...
```

and I think `max` is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: wow, you're kung fu is strong! i never used this kind of syntax. could you suggest me a way to make the average of the elements with different index? directly, with this kind of syntax. also, can you point me to some learning source for functional programming with matlab? is that called so?

Comment: This is not functional programming. Look up MATLAB guides to *vectorization*. But I would start by reaading the official documentation for `bsxfun` and any other function I used that you don't know. If you want to find the average you need to use the `accumarray` function: `accumarray(C,A,[],@mean)`.

Comment: `accumarray(C',A,[],@mean)`. Thanks a lot!